# Merging two shapefiles to show boundaries

Tags: qgis, overlay

[image: Image of Region and district maps that need to be merged]

I need to draw both maps but only show boundaries for the region (blue map) over the district map (maroon). How do I do that without putting regions on top and changing opacity because the opacity messes up my colors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is set the fill color of your region to be transparent.

That way it doesn't mess with the colors as you say because you are not changing the opacity of the entire symbology just the fill color to transparent, the borders of polygons remain unchanged.

Meaning the transparent "region" polygons over your "district" polygons don't have any color blending issues, the color of your "district" polygons will stay as they should be.
[image]
[image]

Edit:
As @Erik commented you can directly set the Fill style drop down list to "No Brush" and it will also remove the fill color
[image]

Edit2:
A third solution is to set the symbol layer type to be an outline (probably the best solution imo after thinking about it).

[image]

Comment: I prefer choosing "no fill" instead of setting the fill to completely transparent. Another option would be to change the symbol to "border - line".

Comment: +1 @Erik I never really look up  the fill style drop down list.

Comment: Thank you, it has worked.